# Handling if condition, session and in_array in php

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops, if-statement

I have to check the session value, and check it with the constant/defined value and perform action.

The below code is not working. What I'm tyring to do is.

if the session value is A, then check it against the list array(i.e $get_abc), and perform some task
if the session value is E, then check it against the list array(i.e $get_ef), and perform some task

```
    <?php
    $_SESSION['get_value'] = "A";

    define ("ABC", serialize (array ("A", "B", "C")));
    define ("D", serialize (array ("D")));
    define ("EF", serialize (array ("E","F")));

    $get_abc = unserialize(ABC);
    $get_d = unserialize(D);
    $get_ef = unserialize(EF);

    if (in_array($_SESSION['get_value'], $get_abc)) {
        .. do abc stuff..
    }else if(in_array($_SESSION['get_value'], $get_d)) {
        .. do d stuff..
    }else if(in_array($_SESSION['get_value'], $get_ef)) {
        .. do ef stuff..
    }else{
        .. do simple query..
    }
    ?>
```

Any help

Comment: try adding session_start(); function at the top of file.

Comment: Sidenote: You need to mention if `session_start();` is indeed loaded. If so, include it in your question/code. If you're not loading it, **do.**

Comment: Anything that you have `unserialized()` is not an array. If you have not done so, please turn on all error reporting and you will see that.

Comment: This `$get_abc = unserialize(ABC);` would probably get confused as constant `ABC` instead of `A or B or C`. It should probably be comma-seperated.

Comment: Separating with commas will give you three undefined constants @Fred-ii-

Comment: So using `$get_abc = unserialize(ABC);` is what should be used? @JayBlanchard

Comment: @JayBlanchard What you mean here _Anything that you have unserialized() is not an array_?

Comment: That `$get_abc = unserialize(ABC);` looked odd to me too, but I just tested it and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: No, @Fred-ii-, that returns a single undefined constant that is not an array. The OP's `$get_`'s should be setup as arrays from the beginning.

Comment: @RiggsFolly when I test that I get an undefined constant, not an array.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Possible silly question, did you load `session_start();`? Since Riggs test was good.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes :-) BUT, let me try something else. I did forget to DEFINE ABC. Once I do that it work fine. :-/

Comment: I just tested it with PHPCLI Using - PHP5.5.8/PHP5.4.16/PHP5.3.22 and all 3 worked just hunky dory

Comment: @RiggsFolly my bad, I forgot to define ABC before testing. Withoout the definition it comes back as a constant. We need to know from the OP what isn't working.

Comment: For all of you confusing with `unserialize(ABC)` its basically a constant containing serialiaze array string. `unserialize(ABC)` will unserialize the serialize string constant as array back to `array ("A", "B", "C")`.

Comment: We're not confused @RahilWazir, we just haven't had proper amounts of caffeine yet.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Ah ok. I just finished it :)

Comment: An answer gets a +1 and [`my comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23954999/handling-if-condition-session-and-in-array-in-php#comment36902156_23954999) didn't; boohoo!! lol a simple addition of `session_start();`, *hmph*. That's it, I'm getting myself a double shot of Espresso.

Comment: yes @Fred-ii- i have tried it myself and got expected output

Comment: That's what I thought @RakeshSharma ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- There you go fred, +1 although Abhishek also +1 did beat you to the punch by a milli second.

Comment: @RiggsFolly It took that much more time to "type" up twice as much text. I like being thorough ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- No excuses now, time to move on. Where are we going next.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yep, my Espresso's ready and as for where to go next... *hm...* anywhere at all, but there are a few SQL questions that I'd of loved to put in an actual "answer" but it's already been taken care of. I'll just go in the kitchen for now and indulge. Cheers

Comment: thanks a lot experts. got a good knowledge sharing with all your answers.. ;) thanks again. This platform helps in getting self-tune with you experts. see you with one more interesting (i would say - with my bad coding) question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add `session_start()`

```
<?php session_start();
    $_SESSION['get_value'] = "A";
    define ("ABC", serialize (array ("A", "B", "C")));
    define ("D", serialize (array ("D")));
    define ("EF", serialize (array ("E","F")));

    $get_abc = unserialize(ABC);
    $get_d = unserialize(D);
    $get_ef = unserialize(EF);

    if (in_array($_SESSION['get_value'], $get_abc)){
      echo 'do abc stuff..';
    }else if(in_array($_SESSION['get_value'], $get_d)) {
        echo 'do d stuff..';
    }else if(in_array($_SESSION['get_value'], $get_ef)) {
        echo ' .. do ef stuff..';
    }else{
         echo '.. do simple query..';
    }
    ?>
```

output :- `do abc stuff..`